# RTL msgbox in Matlab

Tags: matlab, right-to-left

I'm trying to present a msgbox in MATLAB which uses horizontal text alignment 'right'.

Problem is when I'm changing the text alignment, the message text appears out of the box.

```
h = msgbox('Sample Text');
th = findall(0, 'Tag','MessageBox' );
set(th, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'right');
```

Does anyone know to present the user with right-to-left message from Matlab?

Comment: Did you try to change the font to Hebrew?

Comment: @Andrey - which font to change and in which way?

Comment: The font of `th` to Hebrew one, like David

Comment: @Andrey - yes, I've tried this. `set(th, 'FontName', 'David')` just change the font without changing the alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message string in the message box is actually created using the [`text`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/text.html)  function, i.e., it is positioned by two coordinates (neglecting the z-coordinate). To position it with the alignment right, you'll need to get the `position` of the message box and use its `width` argument to define the x position of the message text:

```
h = msgbox('Sample Text');
th = findall(0, 'Tag','MessageBox' );

boxPosition = get(h,'position');
textPosition = get(th, 'position'); 

set(th, 'position', [boxPosition(3) textPosition(2) textPosition(3)]);

set(th, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'right');
```

Since this puts your text exactly to the right border of the box, you'll need to adjust the text slightly to the left:

```
set(th, 'position', [boxPosition(3).*0.95 textPosition(2) textPosition(3)]);
```